# Unable to find a document in Mongodb where exact date match in java

Tags: java, mongodb, automation

Statement: I am trying to get the documents from MongoDB collection (Emp) using java.

Condition: Where it matches with the DOB(Date of birth) of a person.

Problem: However, it never returns a record.

But it works perfectly for other fields such as EmpID or EmpName etc. The document of my collection looks like this,

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d4d9059f0b31921a4916a0c"), 
    "EmpID" : "1001", 
    "EmpName" : "John", 
    "Sal" : 30000.0, 
    "DOB" : ISODate("1989-06-09T18:30:00.000+0000"), 
    "Age" : 31.0
}
```

Please find the following java code that I have tried,

```
BasicDBObject dbo = new BasicDBObject();
dbo.append("DOB", new BasicDBObject("$eq","1989-06-10T00:00:00.000"));

FindIterable<Document> doc = coll.find(dbo);

for (Document dox : doc) 
{   
    System.out.println(dox.toJson());
}
```

Please help

Comment: Your example is confusing. You document value and your query value differ by five and a half hours. And your query value lacks any indicator of offset-from-UTC or time zone, while the document value shown of offset of zero (for UTC itself).

Comment: By the way, on that document value: I suggest always including the optional colon character between the hours and minutes of the offset-from-UTC. So, `+00:00` rather than `+0000`. I have seen at least two libraries that break when encountering a value without the colon.

Comment: Thank you Basil for your answer. Actually MongoDB saves date in UTC format which is generally 5 and half hours shorter than the original date value. I entered the DOB value as 1989-06-10 but it stored as "1989-06-09T18:30:00.000+00:00".

Please refer this:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Date/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ISODate it's needed to pass the `Date` object in `BasicDBObject`, not `String`, also timezone must be provided:

```java
dbo.append("DOB", new BasicDBObject("$eq",new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXX").parse("1989-06-10T00:00:00.000+0000")));
```

For Date Of Birth better to use `$gte` and `$lt` comparition operators together in order to take full range of single day, like that:

```java
Date dayStart = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXX").parse("1989-06-10T00:00:00.000+0000");
Date dayEnd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXX").parse("1989-06-11T00:00:00.000+0000");

BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("Date", new BasicDBObject("$gt", dayStart).append("$lte", dayEnd));
```

Comment: Thank you Andrei, your solution works with a little modification.


Date dayStart = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXX").parse("1989-06-10T00:00:00.000+0000");

Date dayEnd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXX").parse("1989-06-11T00:00:00.000+0000");
   
BasicDBObject dbo = new BasicDBObject("DOB", new BasicDBObject("$gte", dayStart)).append("DOB", new BasicDBObject("$lte", dayStart));